# SUM or SUBTRACTION upon condition in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to do SUM or SUBTRACTION upon certain condition within mysql query.
This is : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69e40/2)

**Condition:**

if `ce_type` is `IN` OR `NULL` then add `payment_amount` in a variable

and

if `ce_type` is `OUT` then i want to subtract `payment_amount` from that variable.

I tried it with this query. But, I don't know how to put condition here.

```
SELECT SUM(payment_amount) as payment_amount
FROM customer_payment_options
WHERE (real_account_id='11' AND real_account_type='HQ')
AND company_id='1'
```

Comment: Is 1 a string? Everybody else seems to think so? :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want conditional aggregation, if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ce_type = 'IN' or ce_type is NULL then payment_amount
                WHEN ce_type = 'OUT' then - payment_amount
           END) as payment_amount
FROM customer_payment_options
WHERE real_account_id = '11' AND real_account_type = 'HQ' AND company_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 3):

IF *ce_type* can only have the values **NULL**, **IN** and **OUT**, the following statement does the job.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(ce_type = 'IN' OR ce_type is NULL,payment_amount,-payment_amount)) as payment_amount
FROM customer_payment_options
WHERE (real_account_id='11' AND real_account_type='HQ')
AND company_id='1';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN ce_type IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 
        CASE ce_type WHEN 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END 
    END 
    * payment_amount) as payment_amount
FROM customer_payment_options
WHERE (real_account_id='11' AND real_account_type='HQ')
AND company_id='1'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be -1 somewhere? Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks buddy. Somehow the negative sign got lost after I tested it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF()` to change it conditionally:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(ce_type = "OUT", -1 * payment_amount, payment_amount)) as payment_amount
FROM customer_payment_options
WHERE (real_account_id='11' AND real_account_type='HQ')
AND company_id='1'
```