# php mysql sum by minus condition

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want sum values, this values than `category`

> Table :

```
id | value | category

1  | 1000  | income

2  | 500   | income

3  | 600   | expense
```

Income is positive and income is negative

For this table i want get `SUM` and return `900` `//1000+500-600`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUM or SUBTRACTION upon condition in mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791226/sum-or-subtraction-upon-condition-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this

```
select sum( if(category='income', value, -1 * value) )
from table
```

From [MYSQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string
>   value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 0):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` INT, `value` INT, `category` VARCHAR(7))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `value`, `category`)
VALUES
    (1, 1000, 'income'),
    (2, 500, 'income'),
    (3, 600, 'expense')
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT (
   SUM(CASE WHEN t.category = 'income' THEN t.value END) -- only sum category = 'income'
    - 
   SUM(CASE WHEN t.category = 'expense' THEN t.value END) -- only sum category = 'expense'
 ) 
  AS total
FROM 
 t
```

**Result**

```
total   
--------
900
```